# Synchronizing the model modifies UNSIGNED BIGINT to UNSIGNED BIGINT(19)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb, synchronize, forward-engineer

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- MySql Workbench 6.2.4
- MariaDB 10

When I try to synchronize the model with the database schema and I have en a table a defined type UNSIGNED BIGINT (that is UNSIGNED BIGINT(20)) then it becomes UNSIGNED BIGINT(19).

The same process with forward engineering works fine to these data types.

**Model**

[image: model]

**Synchronizing model**

[image: Synchronizing model]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`table` (
  `id` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

**Forward engineering**

[image: forward engineering]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test.`table1` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Could it be a bug in MySql Workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to define de type like

```
UNSIGNED BIGINT(20) --OK
```

instead of

```
UNSIGNED BIGINT  --KO
```

MySql [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77418)

---

In practice it seems not to affect as we can see in the example
**Exemple**

```
create table test.biginttest (a BIGINT, b BIGINT(10), c BIGINT(15) ZEROFILL);

INSERT INTO test.biginttest VALUES (-10,10,-10);

INSERT INTO test.biginttest VALUES (9223372036854775808,9223372036854775808,9223372036854775808);

select * from test.biginttest;
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things like `(19)` on the end of `BIGINT` (and other `INTs`) mean nothing.  It does not matter whether it is present or absent.  Nor does the number matter; that is `(20)` is OK, too.

All flavors will compile and perform identically.

Comment: The only difference would be that It could save only 19 digits instead of 20

Comment: No.  A `BIGINT` _always_ has room for 64 bits, one of which may be the sign (`SIGNED`, the default, versus `UNSIGNED`).  If you also say `ZEROFILL`, then the `(n)` says "pad the output with `0s` to `n` digits.  (This is a very rarely used feature.)

Comment: Similarly `INT` always has room for 32 bits (`SIGNED`: +/- 2 billion; `UNSIGNED`: 0 to 4 billion -- usually more than sufficient for an `id`).  32bits = 4bytes, half the size of `BIGINT`.

Comment: I get what you mean, so what would it be the goal of the M here BIGINT[(M)]? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/bigint/ Wouldn't it be easier take M out?

Comment: The _only_ use for `(M)` is if you also say `ZEROFILL`.  Otherwise, it has neither benefit, nor harm.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and (apparently) your synchronization tool, creates a number if you did not supply one; this adds to the confusion.  Removing it is "unnecessary effort" unless it is somehow causing trouble in your sync.